# Google Places Api get category Id

Tags: google-places-api

How I can get place category or category id?
Here all categories and subcategories

```
http://support.google.com/places/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1656882&answer=1722104#category
```

But places api doesn`t return cat_id

Answer (score 0):

The Places API has a slightly different set of ["types"](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types), which are returned in the API's [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResponses) response.

If you add a new place via the API should use these types, whereas bulk uploaded data should use the appropriate code in the help article you mentioned.

Comment: yes, it types, but they are not related to the categories.
and i want only take places, and this place sort by category(not type)